# Batch find a line in html and add some text below it

Tags: html, batch-file, find

I'm struggling with this for few hours, but I can't get it to work properly. What I wanna do is find a line

```
<div id="content">
```

and add few lines below that contain some variables like

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">**var**</a></h2>
    <p class="meta"><span class="date">**var**</span>
    <span class="posted">Posted by <a href="#">**var**</a></span></p>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="entry moreless">
        **var** 
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible? If so how?

--David

Comment: In which language, given which input, with what variations? If it's a bunch of files on a Unix system, `man sed` or maybe Perl.

Comment: Do you want a script or something that automatically finds the line and then puts the variables in underneath?

Comment: umm... I wanna make this in bat, cuz it's quite simple, but if you post a C program here I won't fight against it. And I wanna edit a html file... Everything is in the title.

Comment: Well it can be a script, but if there is some program out there, it will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *much better* tools available to solve this. But it is possible with Windows batch!

Assume the text below is the outermost template file named TEMPLATE.HTML. The content trigger line can be indented, but this solution does not allow extra characters after the trigger. (This limitation could be solved, but it would slow things down)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Sample template for building a page</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The sample content file below (named CONTENT_HTML.TXT) contains variables specified as !varName! and the batch file will use delayed expansion to perform the variable substitution. This means that if you want the content to contain an exclamation, it must be encoded somehow. There are two choices. One is to use the HTML character notation &#33; This works fine for text content, but will not work if you want an HTML comment. For comments I define an !X! variable that will be expanded to !

```
<div class="post">
    <h2 class="title"><a href="#">!TITLE!</a></h2>
    <p class="meta"><span class="date">!DATE!</span>
    <span class="posted">Posted by <a href="#">!AUTHOR!</a></span></p>
    <div style="clear: both;">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="entry moreless">
        Example with exclamation point&#33;<br />
        Another example with exclamation point!X!
    </div>
    <!X!--
      sample comment
    -->
</div>
```

Finally here is a batch file that will put everything together and create an output file named FINAL.HTML. I hard coded the values for the variables, but they could just as easily be passed in as arguments.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set X=^^^!
set TITLE=Sample HTML build
set DATE=%date%
set AUTHOR=Santa Clause
set TEMPLATE="template.html"
set CONTENT="content_html.txt"
set FINAL="final.html"

<%TEMPLATE% (
  for /f %%A in ('type %TEMPLATE%^|find /c /v ""') do (
      for /l %%N in (1 1 %%A) do (
      set "ln="
      set/p "ln="
      echo(!ln!
      set "test=!ln:*<=<!"
      if "!test!"=="<div id="content">" (
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in (%CONTENT%) do echo(%%L
      )
    )
  )
)>%FINAL%
```

There are some limitations with this solution

1. Empty lines (lines containing nothing but spaces) will be stripped from the Content portion. Probably not a problem with HTML. Eliminating this limitation will complicate and slow down the solution.
2. Lines beginning with ; will be stripped from the Content portion. This limitation is easily removed, but the code is ugly looking. It involves specifying <LF> as the EOL character in the final FOR /F loop.
3. The Template file must use the Windows newline standard of <CR><LF>. Unix style files using <LF> will fail with this solution. This also can be solved, but again it will complicate and slow things down.
4. As I stated earlier, the content trigger in the Template can have leading spaces, but it cannot have any trailing characters on the line. Removing this limitation will slow the process down.
5. Lines are limited to 1024 characters in Template
6. Trailing control characters are stripped from each line in Template

Comment: Nice one! We have already made it with php but its reeeaaallly slow so this will be a good solution :). I have to study some stuff bu I will try this later. Sorry for answering a month later but I havent checked  stackoverflow for a bit because I havent got any questions and i did thought that some of my unaswered ones will be answered :).

Comment: @DavidDebnar I modified the code. I added a critical `set "ln="` before reading with `set\p` so that blank lines are handled properly.